# How can I determine which network adapter is SFP+ in CentOS?

Tags: networking, centos, centos6, linux-networking

I have a server which has an SFP+ module. We are going to utilize this to get 10gb speeds. I have adapters em1, em2, em3, em4. How can I determine which adapter is the SFP+ adapter in Centos 6.5?

Comment: Have you tried to use dmesg? dmesg | grep em

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you only have a single 10Gb interface use `ethtool` to show supported speeds.

Comment: Doing so reveals that em3 and em4 are 10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full and 1000baseT/Full. em1 and em2 show 10000baseT/Full. However I was under the impression that this server only had one SFP+ adapter. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Since the only adapter you have is SFP+ adapter, and em1 and em2 show 10000baseT/Full, it seems that you'd better choose em1 or em2 for 10gb speeds.

Comment: Actually, 10000baseT is the incorrect terminology. It should correctly be referred to as 10GBASE-T. I guess the programmer for that system made a bad assumption.

Comment: Yes, maybe you are right, Ron. I have found few articles or related PDFs that detail information about 10000baseT.